# Mod rewrite redirect folder to root and use folder as root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've move mi site files to a subfolder and redirect to it with a .htaccess but I need to denied direct access to this folder or subfolder.

Got this in the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # Block access to hidden files and directories.
  # This includes directories used by version control systems such as Git and SVN.
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # Deny direct access to this directory or any sub-directory
    RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ / [R=301,NC,L]

  # Do not apply redirection to these folders/files for compatibility 
    RewriteRule ^(subdir1|subdir2)(/|$) - [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L,NC]

  # root from sub-directory
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/live/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

When I go to:

```
htt://domain.com/site -> htt://domain.com (CORRECT REDIRECTING)
htt://domain.com/site/unexist-> htt://domain.com (CORRECT REDIRECTING)
htt://domain.com/site/live -> htt://domain.com/site/live/ (NOT REDIRECTING HERE!)
```

***In site/live exists another .htaccess*** with some RewriteRule. Could this be the problem?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteRule ^about-us$ about.php
    RewriteRule ^privacy$ privacy.php
    RewriteRule ^oauth$ index.php

</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php

# Custom error messages / pages                                 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

Comment: Does `/site/live/` have another .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava yes It does, I've updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this code in `/site/live/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Custom error messages / pages                                 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # remove /site/ from URL
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /site/(\S+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

    RewriteRule ^about-us$ about.php
    RewriteRule ^privacy$ privacy.php
    RewriteRule ^oauth$ index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, almost work. I've to remove the %1 from `RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]` because It was redirecting to /live witch doesn't exist (404)

Comment: I meant the rule for live doesn't exist although the directory does, I needed to not be possible to see the site from other than `http://domain.com`. Now It redirects `http://domain.com/site/live` to `http://domain.com` and that's ok.